# Deploying yolov5 model using roboflow into Raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, object-detection, yolov5, roboflow

I was wondering if it is possible to deploy a Roboflow Train model to Raspberry Pi, however, with Raspberry Pi OS instead of Ubuntu, or is it only possible with Ubuntu?

I will appreciate any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it requires the Raspberry Pi to run the 64-bit version of Ubuntu: https://docs.roboflow.com/inference/raspberry-pi

However, there is a local server deployment option you can also try for now if you do want to use Ubuntu: https://blog.roboflow.com/locally-deploy-computer-vision/

- "The [roboflow inference server](https://github.com/roboflow-ai/inference-server) now runs via `npx`. On any machine that supports [tfjs-node](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2022/07/how-roboflow-enables-thousands-of-developers-to-use-computer-vision-with-TensorFlow.js.html) (including any modern 64-bit Intel, AMD, or Arm CPU like the M1 Macbook or the Raspberry Pi 4), simply run `npx @roboflow/inference-server`"